# Conexão Mysql com Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel

Estou fazendo a conexão com o banco de dados `mysql` com `laravel` utilizando o seguinte código no arquivo `database.php`

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'estoque_laravel'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '123456'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Arquivo `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=estoque_laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

Porém quando vou fazer um select no banco, tenho o seguinte erro

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 47:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa colocar as informações de conexão de banco no arquivo `.env`;

Na forma que está fazendo 
`'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'estoque_laravel')` o laravel esta interpretando assim:

> Vá até o arquivo `.env`, procure pela variável `DB_DATABASE` e coloque o
>   valor dela em `database`. Caso não encontre coloque `estoque_laravel`.

Se a variável não estiver informada, irá campo vazio para a variável `database`, porque a validação é se ela existe e não se tem informação nela. Sendo assim, coloque as informações de conexão nas variáveis no arquivo `.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=estoque_laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

Segue exemplo real que estou utilizando. No meu caso localmente eu utilizo o usuário `homestead` e senha `secret`:

arquivo `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

arquivo `config/database.php`

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Se sua configuração está exatamente assim, verifique como você setou a configuração no seu banco, porque por parte do laravel está tudo configurado corretamente.

Comment: Fiz está alteração, mas o erro persiste :/

Comment: O erro é exatamente o mesmo? Com a mesma informação: `Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'`. Foi setado o usuário `root`

Comment: sim, exatamente o mesmo

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Verifique o final dela e faça alguns teste na configuração de acesso no seu banco se está configurado conforme no laravel

Comment: Aquelas configurações são do Laravel 5.0 ? porque estou usando o 5.0

Comment: Sim. Esta configuração é compatível com o laravel 5.0

Comment: Então, as configurações estavam sendo cacheadas pelo servidor, eu limpei o cache e tudo funcionou normalmente